# Stop erase function from running when we resize the canvas

Tags: jquery, canvas

I have added Resizable effect on canvas image so when I click on erase button and its erasing properly But when I click on resize button it's still erasing while dragging and resizing.SO I need to stop eraser function on click of resize button.

I have added jquery from this link https://github.com/boblemarin/jQuery.eraser

**JavaScript**

```js
$(function(){$('#eraserrr').click(function(event){
  $('#redux').eraser();
  $('.image').resizable('destroy');
  $('#draggableHelper').draggable('disable'); 
  event.stopPropagation();
});

$('#resizee').click(function(event) {
  $('#redux').eraser('disable');
  $('.image').resizable();
  $('#draggableHelper').draggable();
  event.stopPropagation();
});
$('#resetBtn').click(function(event) {
  $('#redux').eraser('reset');
  $('#progress').html('0%');
  event.preventDefault();
});
$('#clearBtn').click(function(event) {
  $('#redux').eraser('clear');
  $('#progress').html('100%');
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

**HTML**

```html
<span class="container">
  <img id="robot" src="img/robot.jpg" />
  <div id="draggableHelper">
    <img id="redux" class="image"  src="http://minimal.be/lab/jQuery.eraser/img/robot_redux.png" />
  </div>
  <div id="progress">0%</div>
</span>
<p>
  <div id="resetBtn" class="box"> RESET </div>
  <div id="clearBtn" class="box"> CLEAR </div>
  <div id="eraserrr"> ERASER </div>
  <div id="resizee"> Resize </div>
</p>
```

Comment: I have added... I click on something... **Show us YOUR CODE!!!**

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: hii..Right Now  Ihave no time to edit this question because If I edit this question I cant able to add scripts there because of spacing issues.So please check it in comments.If Yopu dont mind.

Comment: You add the scripts. I will correct it. And please learn to use StackOverflow, by **not ignoring the beginner instructions**. No worries for us, else you will not get correct answers! `:)`

Comment: There are a lot of issues with your code. Your code is not valid. A `<p>` element cannot contain any `div`s inside it.

Comment: leave <p> element..praveen just tell me how to stop erase function when we click on resize button.

Comment: Because it still working when we clcik on resize button..even i have added event.stoppropagation function.

Comment: Praveen you there..?

Comment: Yes, writing answer for you!

Answer (score 0):

Replace the function like this?

```
$(function(){
  $('#eraserrr').click(function(event){
    $('.image').resizable('destroy');
    $('#draggableHelper').draggable('disable'); 
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

Comment: But where is the eraser function when we click on erase function?

$('#redux').erase();

and also giving error annot call methods on draggable prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'disable'

Please check it at your end

Comment: Hello anybody there..??

Comment: Sorry buddy. In office. Give me some time.

Comment: can u give me your email id.?

Comment: Okay @amrinder, please remove your comment with my email address.

Comment: removed praveen..Mr praveen hav you checked the code..Please help me out.

Comment: @amrinder Till yesterday night I didn't get any mails from you. Now I am in the office.

Comment: Hi.Praveen..I have sent you email did u got it..??

Comment: @amrinder Hi, I got your email and responded too, please send me with the files na?